# How to count the number of dashes (-) in a phone number String for input validation?

Tags: java, validation, phone-number

What I have is a program that reads in a user-entered phone number and returns the country code (if it exists), area code (if it exists), and local 7-digit phone number.
The number must be entered as countrycode-area-local. So, the maximum number of dashed you can have in the phone number is two.

For example:
1-800-5555678 has two dashes (it has a country code and area code)
800-5555678 has one dash (it only has an area code)
5555678 has no dashes (only local number)

So, it's OK to have zero dashes, one dash, or two dashes, but no more than two.

What I am trying to figure out is how you would count the number of dashes ("-") in the string to make sure there aren't more than two instances of them. If there are, it would print an error.

So far, I have:

```
if(phoneNumber ///contains more more than two dashed
{
    System.out.println("Error, your input has more than two dashes. Please input using the specified format.");
{
else
{
    //normal operations
}
```

Everything works so far except for this one part. I'm not sure what method to use to do this. I tried looking at indexOf, but I am stumped.

Comment: `1-800-555-1212` isn't a legal phone number?

Comment: @azurefrog This program's requirements do not allow dashes in the 7 digit local phone number. Remember I said countrycode-areacode-local

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way do it would be to parse the number into string and then split on the dashes. If the new array you get is of length greater than 3 then give an error.

```
String s = "1-800-5555678";
String parts[] = s.split("-");
if (parts.length > 3) {
    System.out.println("error");
} else {
    // do something
}
```

A more memory efficient solution as suggested by [samrap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2537637/samrap) is:

```
String s = "1-800-555-5678";
int dashes = s.split("-").length - 1;
if (dashes > 2) {
    System.out.print("error");
} else {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Important to remember that the length of the array will always be one greater than the character you are splitting on. Also, rather than allocate memory for an array which is only needed to find the length, I would suggest doing this:  int dashes = (s.split("-").length) - 1;

Answer (score 1):

```
String phoneNumber = "1-800-5555678";
int counter = 0;
for( int i=0; i< phoneNumber.length(); i++ ) {
  if( phoneNumber.charAt(i) == '-' ) {
    counter++;
  } 
}

if(counter > 2) ///contains more more than two dashed
{
  System.out.println("Error, your input has more than two dashes. Please input using the     specified format.");
{
else
{
 //normal operations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Loop through the chars in the string and see if they are `-`

```
int nDashes = 0;
for (int i=0; i<phoneNumber.length(); i++){
    if (phoneNumber.charAt(i)=='-')
        nDashes++;
}
if (nDashes>2){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex and `replaceAll()` are your friends. Use,

`int count=string.replaceAll("\\d","").length();`

This will replace all the numbers with empty strings and thus all you will be left with is `-`s